# Creating a new JCheckBox makes my interface open infinitely many times

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jcheckbox

I have some code that was working perfectly fine before, but now that I am trying to add another JCheckBox, when I run the code the interface pops open in an infinite loop. The code that is causing it is when I create the new JCheckBox "marathonCheck." Without that line (and without the other marathonCheck operations) the interface opens normally. I'm not sure what is going on.

```
public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener{


    JCheckBox rM;
    JButton rS;
    JFrame jFrame;
    private boolean runeMystery;
    private boolean runScript = false;


    public GUI() {

        jFrame = new JFrame("All in One Start-Up Runecrafter");
        jFrame.setSize(400, 400);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
        jFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

        JCheckBox marathonCheck = new JCheckBox("Would you like to enable marathon mode?"); //<--- THIS IS A PROBLEM
        marathonCheck.setSelected(true);
        if(marathonCheck.isSelected()){
        rM = new JCheckBox("Rune Mysteries Completed?");
        }

        rS = new JButton("Run Script");

        jFrame.add(marathonCheck);

        if(marathonCheck.isSelected()){
        jFrame.add(rM);
        }

        jFrame.add(rS);

        rS.addActionListener(this);

    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

        runeMystery = rM.isSelected();
        runScript = true;
        jFrame.setVisible(false);
        dispose();

    }
```

Comment: `public class GUI extends JFrame` followed by `JFrame jFrame;` seems like a pointless exercise which just generates confusion, which frame are you actually referencing?  I'd get rid of `extends JFrame`

Comment: So, a quick run of your code seems to work fine

Answer (score 0):

Well maybe is not that bad putting the text into the arguments of your JCheckBox but it can help to your problem, also u' need a main to run this and make it run

```
   public GUI() {
    jFrame = new JFrame("All in One Start-Up Runecrafter");
    jFrame.setSize(400, 400);
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
    jFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    JCheckBox marathonCheck = new JCheckBox(); 
    marathonCheck.setText("Would you like to enable marathon mode?");
    marathonCheck.setSelected(true);
    if(marathonCheck.isSelected()){
    rM = new JCheckBox();
    rM.setText("Rune Mysteries Completed?");
    }

    rS = new JButton("Run Script");

    jFrame.add(marathonCheck);

    if(marathonCheck.isSelected()){
    jFrame.add(rM);
    }

    jFrame.add(rS);

    rS.addActionListener(this);

}
```